# What does ChainMap.new_child() return?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm reading [David Beazley & Brian K. Jones 's book "Python Cookbook" (Ed 3)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340377). In pg 35 there's an example of `ChainMap`. I don't quite understand the `values` jumping up and down, pls see my understanding and questions below:

```
>>> values = ChainMap()
>>> values['x'] = 1
```

I suppose now `values` is `ChainMap({'x': 1})`

```
>>> # Add a new mapping
>>> values = values.new_child() 
>>> values['x'] = 2
```

At the end of these 3 lines, what is `values` now? the `ChainMap` or the dictionary inside?

I'm really a bit lost, the codes here meant to me is the `ChainMap` added a new child, which shall be a new dictionary; so `values` becomes a dictionary item **linked by** the `ChainMap`; then `values` is assigned to the new dictionary .

```
>>> # Add a new mapping
>>> values = values.new_child() 
>>> values['x'] = 3
```

But now `values' start to call`new_child()`again! Isnt'`new_child()`can only be called by a`ChainMap`, not a particular`dictionary` it links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great book, I suppose every Python developer should read at least chapters 1 and 4

Concerning your question:

> At the end of these 3 lines, what is values now?

values is `ChainMap` object with 2 dictionaries mapped:

```
values = ChainMap({'x': 1}, {'x': 2})
```

The confusing thing is that the (mutated) object itself is returned from `new_child()` and not the real child.

> But now values' start to callnew_child()again!

Of course you can call `new_child()` as many times as you want, `values` would be always `ChainMap` object with defined method `new_child()`

Comment: thanks! now i got it. ps. the parents property of the ChainMap is really misleading! why not use `cdr`....